# How i implement some props to make my code cleaner on react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I wanna implement some props on my code to understand how it's works.

I build my component  :

```
const [task, setTask] = useState({ task: "", etat: "en cours" });

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const switchEnCours = (taskToSwitch) => {
    setTodoList((todoList) =>
      todoList.map((item) =>
        item === taskToSwitch ? { ...item, etat: "terminé" } : item
      )
    );
  };
function TodoEnCours(props) {
    return todoList.map((insertTask, index) => {
      if (insertTask.etat === "en cours") {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{insertTask.task}</p>
            <button onClick={() => switchEnCours(insertTask)}>
              {insertTask.etat}
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return <div></div>;
      }
    });
  }
```

and i render it on my return

```
<div>
      <input onChange={handleInput}></input>
      <button onClick={AddTask}>Valider</button>
      <div className="DivColonne">
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>
          <TodoEnCours  />
        </div>
```

i wanna put some props on my component but i don't understand how it's works

Comment: I would recommend you read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-an…

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "i wanna put some props **on** my component?

If I got it right, you have two components - A, B - where component B is the son of component A.

If that is correct - and assuming you have imported component B into component A, all you need to do is create the props object you would like to pass to component B - in the form that component B is expecting to receive it.

So if for instance component B is expecting to receive an object, you need to -

- Create the data object you wish to pass
- pass it where you render the component

```
const props={
    "id" : "404ee2da-a296-4981-a8a3-c1a92e69e99d",
    "name" : "Alice",
    ...
}
```

```
<div>
    ....
    <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>
        <TodoEnCours props={props}/>
</div>
```

You have it all in the React docs,
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html